# Aligning equations to the left in latex

Tags: equations, align

I am writing some equations in latex with

```
\begin{dmath}
equation
\end{dmath}
```

By default the equations are centered. I want to align the equations to start from the left of the page. How can I do it?

Comment: It's recommendable to read some beginner stuff like »[lshort](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english)«.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `fleqn` to the document class. Optionally you can use `\mathindent` to adjust the indentation.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,fleqn]{standalone}% change this line back to your own document class (article).
\setlength{\mathindent}{2cm}% you can set it back to 0cm (the default).
\begin{document}
Don't be a lukewarm. If you cannot be the best,
\[
E\ne mc^2
\]
be the worst!
\end{document}
```

[image]